# Silverlight Application_Unhandled exception issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, internet-explorer, silverlight

I have a silverlight application which is hosted in Asp.net website. For fetching data to and fro WCF service is used. User can use both application and website independently.

If asp.net website is logged out by user silverlight application keeps running, but faces timeout issue as WCF service is no longer available as it uses asp.net session.

Silverlight has no way to detect session as no longer active, only workaround is handle wcf timeout exception. Silverlight application also used callbacks to process results.

So instead of going through each call back and catching timeout exception I decided to use Application_Unhandle event to catch timeout exception and if so redirect user to Asp.net login page or show message box to notify user that session is expired please login again.

```
private void Current_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
        if (e.ExceptionObject is System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException) {
            // Inform the user

            // Recover from the error
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Session is expired. Please login again to continue.");

        }

        // Exception is unrecoverable so stop the application and allow the 
        // Silverlight plug-in control to detect and process the exception.                     
    }
```

This works great on my local enviroment.

But when I deploy this on server it does not work.

**Update**

On further investigation I found out that IE's script debugger throws javascript unhandled exception which breaks code execution so code never reaches to silverlight Application_Unhandle code.

**Update 2**

I am getting visual studio Just in Time error.

[image: Just In Time Exception]